# Apache 2.2 how to check if HTTP_HOST SERVER_ADDR are not equal?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2.2

I have tried the below mentioned option but its not working. The condition passes when both are equal AND when both the values are not equal.

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^%{SERVER_ADDR} 
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://hostIsDifferent [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Which problem are you facing?

Comment: In Apache 2.2 http configuration I want to check if HTTP_HOST and SERVER_ADDR are not equal. And do a redirection: A sample is provided below: <br>


  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST},%{SERVER_ADDR} !^(.*),\1
  RewriteRule ^(.*)  http://REDIRECT_TO_MY_PERSONAL_ERROR_URL [R=301,L]